# lambda null pointer exception

Tags: lambda, collections, java-8

I am trying to filter and sort over a collection as follows:

```
List<Tls201Appln> appsFiltered = apps.stream()
                    .filter(x -> x.getTls203ApplnAbstr().getApplnAbstractLg().toLowerCase().equals("en"))
                    .sorted((x1, x2) -> x1.getApplnFilingDate().after(x2.getApplnFilingDate()) ? 1 : x1.getApplnFilingDate().before(x2.getApplnFilingDate())?-1:0)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

And it is throwing the following exception

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at it.jrc.tim.patstat.beans.PatstatExtractorAutumn2015.lambda$0(PatstatExtractorAutumn2015.java:402)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:174)
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1374)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
    at it.jrc.tim.patstat.beans.PatstatExtractorAutumn2015.findLastPatentNumber(PatstatExtractorAutumn2015.java:404)
```

applnFilingDate is a not null property on Tls201Appln. 
Where is the null pointer coming from?

Comment: Perhaps `getTls203ApplnAbstr()` can be null

Comment: You can start by telling us which line is 402 in the code you wrote here. You can split the expression to as many lines as possible and run the code again to see more precisely which sub-expression is the one with the problem

Answer (score 0):

The null pointer exception appears in the second line.
splitting the lambda expression in multiple lines and handling the null pointer exception resolves the problem as follows:

```
List<Tls201Appln> appsFiltered = apps.stream()
                    .filter(x -> {
                        if(x!= null && x.getTls203ApplnAbstr() !=null  && x.getTls203ApplnAbstr().getApplnAbstractLg() != null) {

                            return x.getTls203ApplnAbstr().getApplnAbstractLg().toLowerCase().equals("en");
                        }
                        else return false;
                    })
                    .sorted((x1, x2) -> x1.getEarliestFilingDate().after(x2.getEarliestFilingDate()) ? 1 : x1.getEarliestFilingDate().before(x2.getEarliestFilingDate())?-1:0)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I will never understand why developers are so tenaciously ignoring the existence of methods like `equalsIgnoreCase` and keep constructing new strings via `toUpperCase()` or `toLowerCase()` for a simple comparison. It’s not only inefficient, it’s not even working in all cases.

Comment: And `(x1, x2) -> x1.getEarliestFilingDate().after(x2.getEarliestFilingDate()) ? 1 : x1.getEarliestFilingDate().before(x2.getEarliestFilingDate())?-1:0;` is a quiet convoluted way to say `(x1, x2) -> x1.getEarliestFilingDate().compareTo(x2.getEarliestFilingDate())`, or even shorter `Comparator.comparing(x -> x.getEarliestFilingDate())`…